# input datetime-local value

Tags: php, html, html5

Olá amigos tudo bem ?

No meu banco de dados possuo o date time assim:2018-06-22 12:00:00

no html final fica dessa forma:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="data_contratado" name="data_contratado" value="2018-06-22 12:00:00">
```

Mas no final não consigo exibir o value no campo.

Fazendo-me favor poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Usa o momentjs ele é mais indicado de usar a data de forma mais organizada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Para abranger toda e qualquer data vinda do banco eu faria dessa forma:

```
$dataInput =  $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

> que atenderia as seguintes situações

```
//data completa
$date = new DateTime('2018-06-22 12:00:00');
$dataInput =  $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');                 
echo '<input type="datetime-local" value="'.$dataInput.'">';
//resultado 22/06/2018 12:00

//data incompleta
$date2 = new DateTime('2018-06-22');
$dataInput2 =  $date2->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');               
echo '<input type="datetime-local" value="'.$dataInput2.'">';
//resultado 22/06/2018 00:00
```

> Observe que no segundo caso não há espaço após o dia da data, **invalidando assim a sua solução** `str_replace(' ','T','2018-06-22')` que retornará  `dd/mm/aaa --/-`-

Para testar esses códigos on-line [**PHPTester**](http://phptester.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar dessa forma: `$dateHtml = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($date));` e adicionar o value no html.

Answer (score 2):

consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
str_replace(' ','T','2018-06-22 12:00:00')
```

Mas não sei se é a melhor forma

Comment: gostei da solução!!

Comment: e se a data fosse `2018-06-22`

Comment: Que maravilha de forma de resolver o problema. :)